# Salesforce coding standards and Best practices

Tags: bestpractice

Can somebody share any documents OR links which is related to Salesforce coding standards and Best practices to follow for development.

Comment: Do a google search, there are lots of links available. Check [this post by by Jeff Douglas](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/10/21/force-com-programming-best-practices/). This will give you an overview of Best Practices used in Force.com.

Answer (score 0):

Below blog describes the best practices for apex coding.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices

Let me put those points in short.

1. Bulkify your code: Whenever you are writing a code in salesforce try to handle multiple records in your code using for loop. Do not consider that there will be only one record at a time.
2. Avoid SOQL & DML statements in FOR loop: This might cause 101: Too many SOQL query error or 151: Too many DML Statements run time error.
3. Bulkify Helper class methods: If you are calling a method from your code make sure that the method is capable of processing multiple records at the same time.
4. Try using Collections (List, Set and Maps) and efficient FOR loop.
5. Organising multiple triggers on the same object: This will help in reusing the queried data and avoiding multiple queries.
6. Use SOQL query FOR loop for large sets of data: For example

> for (List acct : [SELECT id, name FROM account]) {
>           // Your logic here
>           accts.add(acct);
>          }

If the query returns 50,000, for loop will break this data into chunks of 200 records and process it.

7. Use Limits class methods to avoid hitting Governor limits.

> ```
> System.debug('Total Number of SOQL Queries allowed in this Apex code context: ' +  Limits.getLimitQueries());
> System.debug('Total Number of records that can be queried  in this Apex code context: ' +  Limits.getLimitDmlRows());
> System.debug('Total Number of DML statements allowed in this Apex code context: ' +  Limits.getLimitDmlStatements() );
> System.debug('Total Number of CPU usage time (in ms) allowed in this Apex code context: ' +  Limits.getLimitCpuTime());
> ```
>
> System.debug('1. Number of Queries used in this Apex code so far: ' +
>   Limits.getQueries());
>       System.debug('2. Number of rows queried in this Apex code so far: ' + Limits.getDmlRows());
>       System.debug('3. Number of DML statements used so far: ' +  Limits.getDmlStatements());
>       System.debug('4. Amount of CPU time (in ms) used so far: ' + Limits.getCpuTime());

8. Use @future appropriately:

   - No more than 10 method calls per Apex invocation
   - No more than 200 method calls per Salesforce license per 24 hours
   - The parameters specified must be primitive dataypes, arrays of primitive datatypes, or collections of primitive datatypes.
   - Methods with the future annotation cannot take sObjects or objects as arguments.
   - Methods with the future annotation cannot be used in Visualforce controllers in either getMethodName or setMethodName methods, nor in the constructor.
9. Test methods to verify large datasets:
10. Avoid hardcoding IDs in Apex or anywhere else like workflow, validation rules etc, as IDs are different for different environment.